# Как изменять цвет текста в зависимости от результатов AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

У меня есть стандартный  AJAX (Без всяких JQuery). Функция, которая записывает полученный ответ в нужное мне поле выглядит так:

```
document.all("Message").innerHTML =  '<i>' + Response + '</i>';
```

Где Message нужное мне поле. Все работает верно за исключением того, что я не могу изменить цвет текста в зависимости от того, занят ли логин. Как это сделать? Пробовал в файле обработчике php просто сделать вот так:`echo "<div style ='color: green'>Ник свободен</div>";`
Но нет, он тогда просто выдает всегда Undefined. Не нравятся ему HTML теги в тегах `<response></response>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передавай в Response так же цвет, в зависимости от результата запроса.
В самом обработчике php просто сделай так:

```
*************************
//Обработка... запроса
*************************
$data["color"] = "green"; //red, blue yellow.. other else в зависимости от результата
$data["text"] = "message";
return или echo json_encode($data); //зависит как реализовано у тебя в скрипте
```

И далее в JS

```
document.getElementById("Message").style.color = Response.color;
document.getElementById("Message").innerHTML =  '<i>' + Response.text + '</i>';
```

Update:

```
if(xmlHttp.status==200) 
{ 
    var Response=JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseXML); 
    document.getElementById("Message").innerHTML = '<i>' + Response.text + '</i>'; 
    document.getElementById("Message").style.color = Response.color; 

}
```

Comment: Сделал как вы сказали, что что-то все равно не работает. Запросы AJAX посылаются, но в ответ я получаю ошибку следующего содержания: error on line 1 at column 36: Extra content at the end of the document. Может быть проблема вот в этой строке? Response = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;? Ведь теперь в тегах <response> лежит массив?